# Count only new people added to payroll based on previous month

Tags: sql-server, query

Every month we have new people added or removed from payroll.
i'm trying to figure out how many new people are added based on the previous month.
The image show an example of how the table is structured and how i wanted to the results show if possible.

This is what i have so far. Count(Distinct) is used because a can receive multiple payments per month.

```
SELECT PaymentMonth,
    COUNT(DISTINCT PersonID) AS CountPersons,
    COUNT(DISTINCT PersonID) - LAG(COUNT(DISTINCT PersonID)) OVER (ORDER BY PaymentMonth) AS MoMDifference

 FROM table WHERE PaymentMonth>= '202105'
   GROUP BY PaymentMonth
```

[image]

Comment: Does it need to be newly added people as distinct individuals or an overall up\down in count like you have? In other words, if one person leaves and two join, do you want to show a difference of 1 (net difference) or 2 (total new individuals)?

Comment: 2 new individuals, because they were not present the previous month

Comment: is it not better to have a hire and terminated date in the persons table and it is a simple query

Comment: @nbk this is a payroll for people that are retired(pension).

Comment: @AaronBertrand i see my mistake with the sample data, thanks for pointing that out.
I want to figure out how many are added based of previous month so if they are removed 1 month and added 2nd it will count as new and appear in newlyadded. That part seems obvious. 
Further, I'm still learning how to use stackexchange so mistakes are bound to happened, but it will be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LAG` to identify the previous month, then simply count the ones which are not exactly one month previous.

This is made more complicated by the fact that `PaymentMonth` is `varchar` instead of `date`. Always store data in the correct format.

```sql
SELECT
  PaymentMonth,
  COUNT(*) AS CountPersons,
  COUNT(*) - LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY PaymentMonth) AS MoMDifference,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN PrevMonth = DATEADD(month, -1, PaymentMonth)
        THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS NewlyAdded
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      LAG(PaymentMonth) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY PaymentMonth) AS PrevMonth
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            CONVERT(date, PaymentMonth + '01', 112) AS PaymentMonth,
            PersonID
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE PaymentMonth >= '202104'
    ) t
) t
WHERE PaymentMonth >= '20210501'
GROUP BY PaymentMonth;
```

Comment: Count(distinct) is used because personID shows up multiple times. A person can receive multiple payments per month.
I know that it's not good practice to use `varchar` for date column , but i have little say in the matter. That's how they made it and it probably won't change anytime soon.

I also tried what you suggested, but i get a conversation failed date/time error

Comment: OK we can `DISTINCT` in a derived table first. Cannot repro conversion error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=00eb0709ab9ef09ed566dde732426248